# How to use void method with Task.factory.fromAsync

Tags: c#, android-asynctask, xamarin, async-await

I am using wcf to perform the task of insert the data. I am using one of wcf void function to insert the user data

```
AceVqbzServiceClient aceVqbzClientService = new AceVqbzServiceClient();
aceVqbzClientService.OpenAsync();
IAceVqbzService aceVqbzTypeService = aceVqbzClientService as IAceVqbzService;

Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            aceVqbzTypeService.BeginSaveUserOrganizationLinking,
            aceVqbzTypeService.EndSaveUserOrganizationLinking,
            objUser_OrganizationDetail, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None);

aceVqbzClientService.CloseAsync();
```

this is the function

Function is not giving any issue when i am using but data is not inserting through this.
Please give me solution so that i can implement this

Comment: @HenkHolterman Such as?

Answer (score 2):

You need the asynchronously wait (with `await`) the `Task` returned from `FromAsync`:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    AceVqbzServiceClient aceVqbzClientService = new AceVqbzServiceClient();
    await aceVqbzClientService.OpenAsync();
    IAceVqbzService aceVqbzTypeService = aceVqbzClientService as IAceVqbzService;

    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                       aceVqbzTypeService.BeginSaveUserOrganizationLinking,
                       aceVqbzTypeService.EndSaveUserOrganizationLinking,
                       objUser_OrganizationDetail, TaskCreationOptions.None);

    await aceVqbzClientService.CloseAsync();
}
```

Comment: Don't you think you should `await` the other Async calls too?

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer but it is not working in my code

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer of my question

```
 try
        {
            AceVqbzServiceClient aceVqbzClientService = new AceVqbzServiceClient();
            aceVqbzClientService.OpenAsync();
            IAceVqbzService aceVqbzTypeService = aceVqbzClientService as IAceVqbzService;

            var asyncResult = aceVqbzTypeService.BeginSaveUserOrganizationLinking( objUser_OrganizationDetail, null, null );
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();


        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            throw;
        }
```

This line of code is working fine